# Is get Property called on construction or only when the Property is called?

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have a piece of code that I would like to set as part of the get {} section of a property. However, inside this section I call a SQL query.

I would like to know if the call will be made when the object is constructed (i.e. Object t = new Object()) or only when the property is called (i.e. string query = Object.SqlQuery).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is only run when the property is called. It's easy to verify this for yourself:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string SqlQuery
    {
        get
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Code was run here!");
            return "foo";
        }
    }    
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Constructing object.");
        MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
        Console.WriteLine("Getting property.");
        string sqlQuery = myObject.SqlQuery;
        Console.WriteLine("Got property: " + sqlQuery);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Constructing object.
Getting property.
Code was run here!
Got property: foo
```

Comment: Thanks for the example as well! That's what made it click for me!

Comment: An example is worth a thousand words. :)

Answer (score 0):

The code inside the get section of your property will only be called when the getter of the property is called. **It will not be called when a new object is created.**

The exception to this is if you are calling the getter of the property from within the constructor of the class.

Answer (score 0):

The sql statement will only be executed when the property is accessed, this is known as [lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading). Use something like sql profiler if you want proof.

Answer (score 0):

The getter of the property is called when you read from it, like so:

```
var yourVar = this.yourProperty;
```

The setter is called when you assign the property, like so:

```
this.yourProperty = yourVar;
```

Does this help?

Comment: Sorry? What do you mena by that comment?

Comment: It means you typed z instead of y multiple times. You already fixed it now so it's OK. :)